# Undefined control sequence. ...\infty} F{_i} \right ) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infy Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph Command \' invalid in math mode

Tags: equations

What's wrong

```
\begin{equation}
 H^{s}\left ( \bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty} F{_i} \right ) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infy} H^s(F_i)
\end{equation}  

Undefined control sequence. ...\infty} F{_i} \right ) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infy
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Command \' invalid in math mode
```

Comment: I would suppose `\infty`, not `\infy`? However, I get a different error message about an unknown command.

Comment: Besides changing `\infy` to `\infty`, don't use `\left`, `\right` constructs.  `\begin{equation} H^{s}\biggl( \bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty} F{_i} \biggr ) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} H^s(F_i)
\end{equation}`

Comment: I think, it should be `F_{i}`, not `F{_i}` too.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Christian Hupfer's answer, some more fundamental guidance for the future:

When LaTeX prints an error message, it breaks or ends the line at the point where the error occurs. Or, more precisely, to quote accurately from the manual:

> The error locator line is broken at the point where TeX stopped reading the input.

In other words (in this case, at least), LaTeX has told you exactly what the problem is. It's told you it's run into some problems after attempting (and failing) to process `\infy`. It's also told you the nature of its problem: "Undefined control sequence".

In other words, what the error message is telling you is: I don't know what `\infy` means. To you this generally means one of two things: Either you've entered an incorrect control sequence (probably a typo - as in this case), or you've attempted to use a valid command which relies on a package you've forgotten to load. For example you would get a similar error if you attempted to use `\mathbb{R}` without loading `amssymb`.

In this case, you've made a typo and have issed `\infy`, when - of course - you mean `\infty` - which is what you used earlier on. I get `\infty` wrong quite a lot ... :P

Comment: Good thorough explanation!